# Magento 2.3.4 possible issues

Tags: magento2, upgrade, magento2.3.3, magento2.3.4

I am planning to upgrade store from **Magento 2.3.3 to 2.3.4**

Are there any possible issues after upgrade?

Please let me know

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Elasticsearch as search engine, search will not work. [see Github issue here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/27112)

Answer (score 0):

I think but i am not sure,
Not a problem in 2.3.4 magento version and some problem after release magento 2.3.4 solved the by Magento Adobe 
And more for information please refer link :-

> https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/release-notes/release-notes-2-3-4-open-source.html

I suggest you upgrade the magento version.